# Workflow Rule - CreatedDate Filter for Implementation

Tags: workflow, filters, bulkification, workflowrule

I'm in the process of implementing a SFDC release for our client.  I've created a workflow rule that creates start and stop times when certain changes are made to a record.

The tasks occur in a sequential order, so when I turn on the rule in a Sandbox environment, I get some weird results.  For instance, a record in the middle of the sequence of events, may have a stop time but no start time.  This is to be expected, but I would like to add a filter criteria so that the workflow rule only fires on newly created records (where the sequence has not yet started).  So that the workflow rule will only fire when new records are created or updated, and not to existing records.

Can you set a filter in a workflow rule to filter based on *CreatedDate*? Something like:

*IF(CreatedDate > NOW() )*

Comment: You can create a rule with Evaluation criteria as "Evaluate the rule when a record is:" Created.

Comment: Yes thanks. I know that part - I don't think my explanation of the issue was very clear.  I want the evaluation criteria to be when records are created or updated, but I don't want it applied to records that are already going through the sequence of events.  In other words, I dont want it applied retroactively, but only to net-new records going forward.

Comment: You can create a separate indicator on which records to be updated